# Problema al crear usar AUTOINCREMENT SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE Productos (

ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Precio varchar(6) NOT NULL,
Cantidad varchar(6) not null,
Descripcion varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

ERROR:

```
Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 2
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MS SQL server se usa IDENTITY para emular el comportamiento de `AUTO_INCREMENT` en MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Productos (

  ID int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key,
  Precio varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  Cantidad varchar(6) not null,
  Descripcion varchar(255)
);
```

Los dos campos de IDENTITY indican en qué valor comienza la enumeración, el segundo indica cuánto aumenta para cada nuevo registro.

Answer (score 0):

Las identidades están compuestas por el número inicial y posteriormente, el incremento que tendrá dicha secuencia, es cómodo el uso de identidades, ya que no tendremos que insertar el valor manualmente y se tendrá un control automático de los consecutivos de una tabla.

```
CREATE TABLE PAISES
(
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
   CODIGOPAIS VARCHAR(4),
   NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
   COMENTARIOS VARCHAR(MAX),
   CREADO DATE,
   MODIFICADO DATE)

   INSERT INTO PAISES (CODIGOPAIS, NOMBRE, COMENTARIOS, CREADO, MODIFICADO) 
   VALUES
  ('MX', 'MEXICO', 'COMENTARIO1', GETDATE(), GETDATE())

  --Con este comando desactivas el uso de identidad

  SET IDENTITY_INSERT  PAISES ON
  INSERT INTO PAISES (id, CODIGOPAIS, NOMBRE, COMENTARIOS, CREADO, 
  MODIFICADO) VALUES
  (2, 'GT', 'GUATEMALA', 'COMENTARIO1', GETDATE(), GETDATE())
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT PAISES OFF
```

Te dejo el link donde hay algunos ejemplos

https://www.respuestasit.com.mx/2018/12/identity-en-sql-server.html

Comment: Si adjuntas algun ejemplo del link por si en el futuro la pagina no esta disponible , tu respuesta quedaria mucho mejor !